# Select and Insert into a temporal table data from a view SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a view in SQL, and I want to select some data depending on certain conditions  , so is it possible to do

```
SELECT  * INTO #TABLE_S FROM VIEW_TABLE
```

Or How do I insert VIEW data into a temporal table in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll work as is written.  Am I missing the point of the question?

Note that if `#TABLE_S` already exists then you should instead use `INSERT INTO #TABLE_S SELECT * FROM VIEW_TABLE`.

Comment: Yes, I was having some issues when the tasble already exists, thanks for the query

Comment: `SELECT <column list> INTO #table...` will create the table for you - and fails for a table that already exists.  Enjoy!